# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state') reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to console log the username and password in onClick in reactjs but I am getting the TypeError. I have definded authenticate function under the constructor of the class. Below is the complete code. Can anyone guide me here?

```
 authenticate(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var details = {
            "email" : this.state.username,
            "password" : this.state.password
        }
        alert(details.username + details.password);


 <input type="email" onChange = {(event,newValue) => this.setState({username:newValue})} className="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" required="required" />

<input type="password" onChange = {(event,newValue) => this.setState({password:newValue})} className="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" required="required" />

<button className="btn w-100 mt-3 mt-sm-4" onClick={this.authenticate} type="submit">Sign In</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var details = {
            "email" : this.state.username,
            "password" : this.state.password
        }
        alert(details.username + details.password);
```

In this right here, you call for `details.username` but details will only have the keys `email` and `password`.

So basically, `details.username` is undefined, and you can't read that property.

Try changing it to

```
var details = {
                "email" : this.state.username,
                "password" : this.state.password
            }
            alert(details.email + details.password);
```